# how to include extension attributes in rest API call of products?

Tags: magento2, plugin, extension-attributes

I have made a drop-down named `test_attribute` and `multi_attribute` for products and I want to show that into API call of products as well I have made `extension_attributes.xml` but nothing in `extension_attributes.xml` shows up an API call can somebody help?

`extension_attributes.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface">
        <attribute code="multi_attribute" type="string[]" />
          <attribute code="test_attributee" type="int" />
           <attribute code="is_featured" type="string" />
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

`db_schema.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table comment="Catalog Product Table" engine="innodb" name="catalog_product_entity" resource="default">
        <column comment="Featured Product" length="64" name="is_featured" nullable="true"  xsi:type="varchar"/>
    </table>
</schema>
```

`di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <!-- <preference for="FSD\Test\Api\ProductsInterface" type="FSD\Test\Model\ProductsManagment"/> -->
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface">
        <plugin name="product_repository_plugin" type="FSD\Test\Plugin\ProductRepositoryInterface" />
    </type>
</config>
```

`productRepositoryInterface.php`

```
<?php
namespace FSD\Test\Plugin;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductExtensionInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductExtensionFactory;

class ProductRepositoryInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ProductExtensionFactory
     */
    private $extensionFactory;

    /**
     * @param ProductExtensionFactory $extensionFactory
     */
    public function __construct(ProductExtensionFactory $extensionFactory)
    {
        $this->extensionFactory = $extensionFactory;
    }
    public function afterGet(
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $subject,
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface $entity
) {
    $ourCustomData = $this->customDataRepository->get($entity->getId());

    $extensionAttributes = $entity->getExtensionAttributes(); /** get current extension attributes from entity **/
    $extensionAttributes->setOurCustomData($ourCustomData);
    $entity->setExtensionAttributes($extensionAttributes);

    return $entity;
}
public function afterSave(
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $subject,
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface $entity
) {
    $extensionAttributes = $entity->getExtensionAttributes(); /** get current extension attributes from entity **/
    $ourCustomData = $extensionAttributes->getOurCustomData();
    $this->customDataRepository->save($ourCustomData);

    return $entity;
}

    /**
     * Loads product entity extension attributes
     *
     * @param ProductInterface $entity
     * @param ProductExtensionInterface|null $extension
     * @return ProductExtensionInterface
     */
    public function afterGetExtensionAttributes(
        ProductInterface $entity,
        ProductExtensionInterface $extension = null
    ) {
        if ($extension === null) {
            $extension = $this->extensionFactory->create();
        }

        return $extension;
    }
}
```

`UpgradeData.php`

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © FoodServiceDirect, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace FSD\Test\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;

class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
    /**
     *
     * @var type
     */
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     *
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.1.1', '<')) {
            $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
            $eavSetup->addAttribute(
                    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
                       'test_attribute',
                        [
                           'group' => 'General',
                           'type' => 'int',
                           'label' => 'Include Test Attribute',
                           'user_defined' => false,
                           'backend' => '',
                           'input' => 'boolean',
                           'visible' => true,
                           'wysiwyg_enabled'   => false,
                           'source' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean::class,
                           'required' => false,
                           'sort_order' => 150,
                           'default' => '0',
                           'global' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                           'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                           'visible_on_front' => false,
                        ]
               );

        }
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.1.4', '<')) {
            dd("jfjf");
            $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
            $eavSetup->addAttribute(
                    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
                       'multi_attribute',
                        [
                           'group' => 'General',
                           'label' => 'Multiselect Attribute',
                           'type'  => 'text',
                           'input' => 'multiselect',
                           'source' => 'FSD\Test\Extension\Model\Config\Product\Extensionoption',
                           'required' => false,
                           'sort_order' => 30,
                           'global' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
                           'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                           'backend' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\ArrayBackend',
                           'visible_on_front' => false,
                           'visible' => true
                        ]
               );

        }
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.3.1', '<')) {
         
            $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
            $eavSetup->addAttribute(
                    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
                    'test_attributee',
                    [
                       'group' => 'General',
                       'type' => 'int',
                       'label' => 'Include Test Attribute',
                       'user_defined' => false,
                       'backend' => '',
                       'input' => 'boolean',
                       'visible' => true,
                       'wysiwyg_enabled'   => false,
                       'source' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean::class,
                       'required' => false,
                       'sort_order' => 150,
                       'default' => '0',
                       'global' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                       'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                       'visible_on_front' => false,
                    ]
               );

        }
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.4.0', '<')) {
         $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
         $eavSetup->addAttribute(
                 \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
                    'multi_attribute',
                     [
                        'group' => 'General',
                        'label' => 'Select Titles',
                        'type'  => 'text',
                        'input' => 'multiselect',
                        'source' => 'FSD\Test\Model\AllTitles',
                        'required' => false,
                        'sort_order' => 30,
                        'global' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
                        'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                        'backend' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\ArrayBackend',
                        'visible_on_front' => false,
                        'visible' => true
                     ]
            );

     }


        $setup->endSetup();
}
}
```

Comment: Please follow the reference link : https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Programming/how-to-get-custom-attributes-in-rest-search-api/td-p/488423

Comment: @MohdShahbaz any help on this ? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/354339/adding-shipping-price-as-in-customer-group-in-admin-product

Comment: I will answer on it if got something usefull.